# Updating The name of already existing field to something else in NiFi

Tags: regex, apache, etl, apache-nifi

Is there a way I can update the name of existing field in the CSV file to a new name. I know we can use updaterecord processor. But can someone tell me what config to set?

Current i am using CSVreader and CSVSetWritter with Recordpath value and adding a new property:

**Property             Value**

**/oldname     ${field.name:replace('oldname','newname')}**

It is not changing the name of the field. Can anyone help me here? thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your `csv reader controller service` with `old name` and `csv Writer controller service` with `new name` for the field.

Then **swap the data** from `old name -> new name`

**UpdateRecord configs:**

As Replacement Value Strategy

```
Record Path Value
```

Add new property as

**/newname** value as

```
/oldname
```

[image]
For more details refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/189642/update-the-contents-of-flowfile-by-using-updaterec.html) article as i have swapped the data from **id field to rename_id field.**